# Using SQL Server CE 3.5 on Azure Cloud Service Hosting using web role

Tags: sql, azure, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

We have hosted a asp.net 4.0 application on Azure Cloud Hosting service using web role. We are using SQL Server CE 3.5 dll and inserting some data to `.sdf` file. Getting the following error message while opening connection to SQL Server CE `.sdf` file.

> Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

Tried `DbProviderFactories`, runtime tags with in web.config still issue is same. And also tried deployable dependency option on solution as well as private installation for SQL Server Compact as suggested in this article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33661/Creating-a-Private-Installation-for-SQL-Compact  , still issue remain.

If I use SQL Server CE 4.0, it's working fine, it's able to insert data and return `.sdf` file. But with SQL Server CE 3.5 it's giving the above error, we need specifically 3.5 as we are going to send this `.sdf` file to mobile application through web service.

How to use SQL Server CE 3.5 on Azure cloud hosting service? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

thanks and regards,
hari.

Comment: Have you followed my guidance here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html ?

Comment: yes.. tried that.. those dll are available in bin folders with amx64 and x86.. after publishing the ce 4.0 dlls are automatically added in bin folders along with 3.5 dlls which was copied manually..  except the entity framework dll as we are not using them... still the same issue.. the procedure works with 4.0 not 3.5 dlls...

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework 4 or 5. That won't work.

Comment: No we are not using entity framework.

Comment: And you reference assembly version 3.5.1.50 ?

Comment: yes, that is the version..

Answer (score 1):

It could be environmental - Could you test the value of these two statements:

```
string envVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");

Assembly entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string str2 = (entryAssembly == null) ? string.Empty : Path.GetDirectoryName(entryAssembly.Location);
```

(This is code from the 3.5 SP2 ADO.NET provider) -
str2 should be the path to your web app bin folder
- envVar should be the folder name for the processor architecture (X86 or AMD64)

In 4.0, the logic to get the path (str2) has been improved:

```
string localPath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
Path.GetDirectoryName(localPath);
```

I think the logic has been improved in 4.0 to better support web deployment. In other words: Private Web Deployment with SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 is not supported.

Options: Use host that has 3.5 SP2 installed, use 4.0 and modify the version header of the file (have not tried this, but could be an option) See http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html

Comment: str2 value is empty. Role root dir is F:\. Approot dir is F:\sitesroot\. As I am using local storage the storage path is C:\Resources\directory\1481e60ba17e4462a598da5af1476fd1.EnTrack.EnTrackHHT\.

Comment: localpath value is E:\sitesroot\0\bin\EnTrack.DLL and directory name value is E:\sitesroot\0\bin

Comment: Is there any other option for using 3.5? or if we use sql ce 4.0 is it supported in windows mobile or ce versions?

Comment: No 4.0 is not supported on Windows Mobile/CE. Updated answer

Comment: If we manually copy the 3.5 dlls in bin folder it is working fine in azure cloud environment. Thanks for all the support Eric. Appreciated..